# App Engine is not supported for python 3 in pycharm

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm

I want to create a google app engine project in pycharm. I select python 3, give my project a name.
And it's written that App Engine is not supported for the selected interpreter
I can choose python 2.7 and it is working but why can't I choose python 3.6? I even tried 3.5, same problem. However in official documentation it supports python 3.6... 
I'm sure I have installed google app **flexible** environment

I'll leave there a screen of pycharm just in case [gdrive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7m9t_eQl0ODU0R6anFIUXRFd1E/view?usp=drivesdk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK PyCharm's GAE support means:

- ability to run/debug a GAE app project using the SDK's `dev_appserver.py` - which is only supported for the standard environment
- ability to deploy on GAE using the SDK utilities - which not long ago didn't even support well apps with multiple standard environment services - I had to deploy my app manually.

In other words PyCharm doesn't offer real/significant benefits for the flexible env GAE apps, you'll have to complement it with manual ops or scripts anyways.

So I'd just create a regular python 3.5/3.6 project and simply not specify it's also a GAE project.

Comment: Hi Dan, I agree with totally you. Can you give some base information or a link about deploying a regular python 3.6 project to Google Cloud App. It would be a complete solution to the question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have an example - I'm still a standard env user. But I'd start with the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart) and [Testing and Deploying your Application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/testing-and-deploying-your-app). You'll have to adjust for setting up the virtualenv and setting the Run/Debug configurations in PyCharm to match the command-line instructions. Then you can develop/run/debug you app locally through PyCharm while still managing you deployments directly, using the SDK.

Comment: Officially PyCharm doesn't support App Engine Flexible Environments yet (04/04/2018.) You can check its status here - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15351